# UserEntryListener is not invoked when user created in liferay 6.0.6

Tags: java, jboss5.x, liferay-6

I define a UserEntryListener in liferay hook:

```
package com.ggd543.liferay.listener;

public class UserEntryListener extends BaseModelListener<User> {


    @Override
    public void onAfterCreate(User model) throws ModelListenerException {
        System.out.println("==== onAfterCreate - uuid: " + model.getUuid());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAfterRemove(User model) throws ModelListenerException {
        System.out.println("==== onAfterRemove - uuid: " + model.getUserId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAfterUpdate(User model) throws ModelListenerException {
        System.out.println("==== onAfterUpdate user - uuid: " + model.getUuid());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeforeCreate(User model) throws ModelListenerException {
        System.out.println("==== onBeforeCreate - uuid: " + model.getUuid());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeforeRemove(User model) throws ModelListenerException {
        System.out.println("==== onBeforeRemove - uuid: " + model.getUuid());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeforeUpdate(User model) throws ModelListenerException {
        System.out.println("==== onBeforeUpdate user");
    }
}
```

and in `docroot/WEB-INF/src/portal-ext/properties`:

```
value.object.listener.com.liferay.portal.model.User=com.ggd543.liferay.listener.UserEntryListener
```

After deploy the hook onto liferay 6.0.6 bundled with Jboss 5.1.0 GA,  I found that no matter create, update and  remove action is performed through control pannel , the corresponding callback method of `UserEntryListener` is unable to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've included the properties hook in liferay-hook.xml:

```
<hook>
...
  <portal-properties>portal-ext.properties</portal-properties>
...
</hook>
```

I'm assuming here that there's a typo in your question - `docroot/WEB-INF/src/portal-ext/properties` should read `docroot/WEB-INF/src/portal-ext.properties` - am I right?